# How to connect salesforce with MIConnect

Tags: integration

Hello everyone,
                 I want to connect my salesforce organization with mIConnect,

I don't have more idea about salesforce to [MiConnect](http://www.mita-teknik.com/solutions/turbine-control/miconnect-app/) integration.

any help will be appriciable.